# Replace single spaces and hyphens between spaces in file names

Tags: filenames, rename

I have a bunch of files named like this:

```
File one - some name - 01-05-2020  
File two - some name - 01-07-2020  
File three - some name - 01-15-2020
```

What I need is to replace:

- Single spaces with a hyphen.
- Hyphens between spaces with an underscore.

My expected result would be:

```
File-one_some-name_01-05-2020  
File-two_some-name_01-07-2020  
File-three_some-name_01-15-2020
```

PD: I'm using Manjaro which is Arch based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution with `mv`and `sed`:

```
for file in *; do echo mv "$file" "$(echo $file | sed 's/ - /_/g ; s/ /-/g')" ; done
```

Remove first echo to commit changes.

Tests

```
$ for file in *; do echo mv "$file" "$(echo $file | sed 's/ - /_/g ; s/ /-/g')" ; done
mv File one - some name - 01-05-2020 File-one_some-name_01-05-2020
mv File three - some name - 01-15-2020 File-three_some-name_01-15-2020
mv File two - some name - 01-07-2020 File-two_some-name_01-07-2020
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I was looking for, thank you @Paulo Tomé

Comment: needs to escape the " eg:
`for file in *; do echo mv \"$file\" "$(echo $file | sed 's/ - /_/g ; s/ /-/g')" ; done`

Answer (score 0):

Using Larry Wall's "perl rename" (`rename` on Debian/Ubuntu, `prename` on RHEL/Centos/Fedora):

```
rename -n -E 's/ - /_/g' -E 's/ /-/g' {file[s]}
```

Remove `-n` (or replace by `-v`) for actual execution.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `rename: invalid option -- 'E'`, I forget to specify my distro, I'm using Manjaro which is Arch based, maybe it has something to do with this?

Comment: There are many commands called `rename`.  `man rename` should mention `Larry Wall` in the `AUTHOR` section at the end. On ArchLinux (and therefore Manjaro)  Manjaro it seems to be in the `perl-rename` package.

Comment: Indeed it is perl-rename, but it gives me the same error. When I check the available options with `--help` there is no -E.

Comment: On mine `rename -V` says `/usr/bin/rename using File::Rename version 0.20`. It takes both `-e` and `-E`, the difference being that `-E` adds a `;` at the end and as far as I can tell this is required if you have more than one command.